# Doing math with input type="time"

Tags: javascript, math, input, time, types

I'm trying to do a time calculator using the input type="time" value, but getting NaN as a result. Here's my code:

```js
document.getElementById("MathButton").onclick = timeCalc;

function timeCalc() {

    let startTime = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
    let endTime = document.getElementById("endTime").value;
    let diff = endTime - startTime;
    document.getElementById("diff").innerHTML = (diff);
    console.log(diff);
    console.log(startTime, endTime);
```

```html
<div>
        <p>START</p>
        <input type="time" id="startTime" name="start" value="08:00"><br />
        <p>END</p>
        <input type="time" id="endTime" name="end" value="16:30">
        <br />
        <button id="MathButton">Calculate!</button>
        <br />
        <p>Total: <br /> <span id="diff"></span>&nbsp; hours.</p>
    </div>
```

I just can't get it to do the math, but I can see that both values are present if I add startTime and endTime to the console log.

**I accepted Doan's answer as correct as it is the least amount of code and gets the job done. I was able to understand that he took my times and made them into date objects, but since I am relatively new to this I was hoping for more of an explanation. Was able to figure it out though, and get my next part of the program built using this knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```js
document.getElementById("MathButton").onclick = timeCalc;

function timeCalc() {
    let startTime = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
    let endTime = document.getElementById("endTime").value;

     //create date format          
     var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + startTime );
     var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + endTime );

     var diff= timeEnd - timeStart;             

     diff= diff/ 60 / 60 / 1000;
     document.getElementById("diff").innerHTML = (diff);
}
```

```html
<div>
        <p>START</p>
        <input type="time" id="startTime" name="start" value="08:00"><br />
        <p>END</p>
        <input type="time" id="endTime" name="end" value="16:30">
        <br />
        <button id="MathButton">Calculate!</button>
        <br />
        <p>Total: <br /> <span id="diff"></span>&nbsp; hours.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting two strings will result into NaN. Here, I have converted both the strings to date first and then subtracted it. Since substracting two dates gives the result in millisecond, `result/ 60 /60 /1000` converts it to hours.

```js
document.getElementById("MathButton").onclick = timeCalc;

   function timeCalc() {

let startTime = new Date().toDateString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + document.getElementById("startTime").value;
let endTime = new Date().toDateString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + document.getElementById("endTime").value;
let diff = (new Date(endTime) - new Date(startTime)) / 60/ 60 / 1000;
document.getElementById("diff").innerHTML = (diff);
console.log(diff);
}
```

```html
<div>
        <p>START</p>
        <input type="time" id="startTime" name="start" value="08:00"><br />
        <p>END</p>
        <input type="time" id="endTime" name="end" value="16:30">
        <br />
        <button id="MathButton">Calculate!</button>
        <br />
        <p>Total: <br /> <span id="diff"></span>&nbsp; hours.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just subtract two string first you have to convert them to integers to apply mathematical operations to them. Just split them by ':' like-

```
         startTime.split(":") 
         endTime.split(":") 
         diff = toString(startTime[0]- startTime[0])+":"+toString(startTime[1]- 
         startTime[1])
```

this will form a list then excess the elements by index to subtract them startTime[0] for hours and so on